# What is the purpose of 'nice' command without a niceness parameter?

Tags: linux, nice

I often see this code in anacrontab samples on the internet:

```
# environment variables
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
RANDOM_DELAY=30
# Anacron jobs will start between 6am and 8am.
START_HOURS_RANGE=6-8
# delay will be 5 minutes + RANDOM_DELAY for cron.daily
1               5       cron.daily              nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7               0       cron.weekly             nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly        0       cron.monthly            nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

'nice" command as explained by "man nice" if for changing a program priority with a niceness parameter. However I do not understand the 'nice' command in the above sample if we do not add a niceness parameter.

Comment: what does nice take as default if you don't specify anything...

Answer (score 7):

From the manual:

```
   -n, --adjustment=N
          add integer N to the niceness (default 10)
```

So, `nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily` is actually the same as any of the following:

```
nice -10 run-parts /etc/cron.daily
nice -n 10 run-parts /etc/cron.daily
nice -n +10 run-parts /etc/cron.daily
```

Comment: So I think I begin to understand. I believed it was useless because it set the value to the default. But this is not the overall default process niceness, it is the default for the nice command only (10). And it IS NOT necessarily what is the default niceness of the process (by the way most mine have 0 as niceness). Is this correct?

Comment: The default adjustment in the `nice` command is indeed something different then the default niceness of a process. I think it helps to use the term _adjustment_ for the `nice`-command.

Comment: About `nice -10` being equivalent to `nice -n 10`: [*Why does `nice` with a negative argument (e.g. `nice -15`) increment niceness?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/772831/108618)